# Why Use Start Activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've been looking through the API documentation, and noticed starting with API level 16 the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class includes the following method:

`public abstract void startActivities (Intent[] intents)`

I've been Googling around in attempts to stave my curiosity through an example of it's use in application code, a question, or article, but I haven't come across anything as of yet.  If someone has already asked a similar question, please let me know.

Anyways, I'm curious as to when this should/could be used in application code, and what (if any) benefits of doing so would be?  I've personally never seen this method used, and I fail to grasp it's utility.  Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's rarely used in application code. I was going to say never, but I'm not *that* sure ;)

However, it *can* be used to create a *synthetic* back stack, when starting a new Task. You want to have a ready-made back stack, so that the back key navigates "hierarchically" inside this task.

Curiously, it's better explained in the [documentation of `ContextCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#startActivities%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%5B%5D%29) than in `Context` itself.

> Start a set of activities as a synthesized task stack, if able.
>
> In API level 11 (Android 3.0/Honeycomb) the recommended conventions
>   for app navigation using the back key changed. The back key's behavior
>   is local to the current task and does not capture navigation across
>   different tasks. Navigating across tasks and easily reaching the
>   previous task is accomplished through the "recents" UI, accessible
>   through the software-provided Recents key on the navigation or system
>   bar. On devices with the older hardware button configuration the
>   recents UI can be accessed with a long press on the Home key.
>
> When crossing from one task stack to another post-Android 3.0, the
>   application should synthesize a back stack/history for the new task so
>   that the user may navigate out of the new task and back to the
>   Launcher by repeated presses of the back key. Back key presses should
>   not navigate across task stacks.
>
> startActivities provides a mechanism for constructing a synthetic task
>   stack of multiple activities. If the underlying API is not available
>   on the system this method will return false.

Comment: Just adding this as a comment for a potential update, but adding an update for deeplinks (Synthesize a new Back Stack for Deep Links):  https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: It's also useful for developing a piece of application code that's buried deep within the app.

Answer (score 1):

Never used it myself, but I think it is useful when you want to recreate your activity stack, when starting a new fresh task. For example when your application gets launched from a notification, the system won't use an existing task for your application but instead create a new task with your application on it by default. In this case you may want to start on a certain position of your activity stack, and with this method you could start all your activities with one call

Answer (score 0):

I have used the method. In some specific sutiation, I clear the task stack when I create a new activity .But when I back to the activity which was already cleared in the task stack, I used the `startActivities()` to create a aritificial task stack.