# Android call 2 or more classes from main activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android. I have main activity from which I need to call different classes to perform different functions. But whenever I call two classes at same time, only the last intent is called. Can someone suggest a way to call 2 or more classes at the same time in an activity. Thank you

Below is my code example

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Api mApi;
    Button  data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);



        //calling sygic truck api and implementing sygic call back
        mApi = Api.init(getApplicationContext(), "com.sygic.truck", "com.sygic.truck.SygicService", mApiCallback);
        //connecting sygic app
        mApi.connect();



        data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), locationInfo.class);

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), routeInfo.class);

                Intent[] list = new Intent[2];
                list[0] = intent1;
                list[1] = intent2;
                startActivities(list);

            }
        });

    }




}
```

---

**locationInfo class**

```
public class locationInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Api mApi;
    public TextView coordinates;
    public String currentLocation = "";
    public String longitude;
    public String latitude;
    public Button data;
    public String altitude, speed;

    public int speedLimit;

    //calling gps class from sygic lib
    GpsPosition gpsPos = new GpsPosition();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);




        // sygicGetData();
        try {
            Log.v("debug", "Location is...1" );
            boolean satInfo = true;
            int maxTime = 0;

            gpsPos = ApiNavigation.getActualGpsPosition(satInfo, maxTime);
            longitude = String.valueOf(gpsPos.getLongitude());
            latitude = String.valueOf(gpsPos.getLatitude());
            altitude = String.valueOf(gpsPos.getAltitude());
            speed = String.valueOf(gpsPos.getSpeed());
            speedLimit = ApiInfo.getCurrentSpeedLimit(maxTime);
            Log.v("debug", "Location is...2" );
            Position pos = new Position();
            pos.setPosition(gpsPos.getLongitude(), gpsPos.getLatitude());
            currentLocation = ApiLocation.getLocationAddressInfo(pos, maxTime);


            coordinates.setText("\n" + "Current Location:" + currentLocation + "\n" + "Longitude:" + longitude + "\n" + "Latitude:" + latitude +
                    "\n" + "Altitude:" + altitude + "\n" + "Current Speed:" + speed +
                    "\n" + "Speed Limit:" + speedLimit);

        } catch (GpsException e) {
            Log.e("GpsPosition", "Error code:" + e.getCode());
        } catch (InvalidLocationException e) {
            Log.e("Location", "Error code:" + e.getCode());
        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**routeInfo class**

```
public class routeInfo extends AppCompatActivity  {

    public String remainingDistance, remainingTime;
    public String totalDistance, totalTime;
    public Button data;
    public TextView coordinates;
    public RouteInfo routeInfo;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        coordinates = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        // sygicGetData();
        try {
            boolean info = true;
            int maxTime = 0;

            routeInfo = ApiNavigation.getRouteInfo(info, maxTime);
            totalDistance = String.valueOf(routeInfo.getTotalDistance());
            remainingDistance = String.valueOf(routeInfo.getRemainingDistance());
            totalTime = String.valueOf(routeInfo.getTotalTime());
            remainingTime = String.valueOf(routeInfo.getRemainingTime());

            coordinates.setText("\n" + "Total Travel Distance:" + totalDistance + "\n" + "Remaining Travel Distance:" + remainingDistance + "\n" + "Total Travel Time:" + totalTime + "\n" +
                    "Remaining Travel Time:" + remainingTime + "\n");

        } catch (GpsException e) {
            Log.e("GpsPosition", "Error code:" + e.getCode());
        } catch (InvalidLocationException e) {
            Log.e("Location", "Error code:" + e.getCode());
        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jackfruit.sygicdata4">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".getters.locationInfo"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".getters.routeInfo"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what happens when you press the back button after last Activity gets launched?

To the best of my knowledge, startActivities() is only used to construct a synthetic back stack, not launch activities in serial

This link has more info: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295906/why-use-start-activities)

Comment: Hi Srinivas, on pressing back button it calls first intent. Is there a way I call both together?

Comment: Also define two classes at the same time. Only 1 activity can be at the top of the stack at any given point of time. startActivities doesn't start 2 activities and have them run simultaneously

Comment: So pressing back when in the top of the stack takes you back to Main Activity?

Comment: No to the first intent, that is the locationInfo class

Comment: aha, so it does what it is supposed to, I'l answer this question now

Comment: Can you suggest me a way where I can create different classes and call them together in main activity. I know now that only one activity can be active, so is there a way to call classes in main activity and invoke them there?

Comment: I've given you a way to run the 2 classes in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

```
startActivities()
```

is used to construct something called a synthetic back stack.

In an app when you move from 1 activity to another without invoking a

```
finish()
```

in any of the activities you construct something called a "backstack". It is called a back stack because it is the stack of activities that get restored when you keep pressing the back button.

If you wanted to artificially create a backstack you would

```
-startActivities()
```

What this does is artificially insert everything but the activity of the last intent into the backstack.

If you wanted to run activit 1 and then run activity2 
just call

```
startActivity()
```

on them separately

If you want the 2 to tasks to run in parallel you need to use something called "AsyncTask". Literature [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I thought async task are used normally to get or send something to url link

Comment: that's not the only use. An Async Task is something you do not block the UI thread. 

For example, as you pointed out, network calls if done on the main thread have a potential to block, so they are done using an async task. You can also use Android Handlers and Thread pool variants. But Async tasks should also work

Comment: can you post an example of async task for my case, as others I find are all for url links?

Comment: [This](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html) sould help. The "doInBackground" method runs everything in another thread, refactor your code to suit the AsyncTask design

Comment: @GauravRam did this help?

Comment: I am still thinking where to implement the Async Task. In other classes or main activity. If I implement in main activity then there will be no difference. Also if I still implement in different classes, like you said earlier only one activity is active at a time. I'm confused now.